# Loading sprite with asset manager LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, sprite, assets

How do I load a sprite with the .assets.load("file", file.type) what should the file type be for a sprite, in this instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, that you usualy don't load a `Sprite` directly, but you load it's `Texture` and create a `Sprite` out of it.
So you call `assets.load("file", Texture.class)` and then create a `Sprite` with the `Texture` you loaded:
`Sprite sprite = new Sprite(asstes.get("file", Texture.class))`.

But i suggest you to use `TextureAtlas` instead of `Texture`.
A `TextureAtlas` is some kind of "Texture-Collection", it is basicly a big `Texture`, which has all the single `Texture`s in itself.
You can load it using `assets.load("atlas", TextureAtlas.class)`
and get it using:
`TextureAtlas atlas = assets.get("atlas", TextureAtlas.class)`.
You can then create your `Sprite` like this:
`Sprite sprite = atlas.createSprite("spriteName");`

To create a `TextureAtlas` you could use the [`TexturePacker`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer).

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to directly load a sprite. When a context loss occurs on Android, it will free the memory that was occupied with your loaded assets. Therefore directly accessing your assets after a context loss would immediately crash a resumed application.

To prevent the above issue you should use an AssetManager which loads and stores assets like textures, bitmapfonts, tile maps, sounds, music and so on. By using an AssetManager you will have to load every asset only once.

My recommended way of doing this is as follows:

```java
// load texture atlas
final String spriteSheet = "images/spritesheet.pack";
assetManager.load(spriteSheet, TextureAtlas.class);
// blocks until all assets are loaded
assetManager.finishedLoading();
// all assets are loaded, we can now create our TextureAtlas object
TextureAtlas atlas = assetManager.get(spriteSheet);

// (optional) enable texture filtering for pixel smoothing
for (Texture t: atlas.getTextures())
    t.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

// Create AtlasRegion instance according the given <atlasRegionName>
final String atlasRegionName = "regionName";
AtlasRegion atlasRegion = atlas.findRegion(atlasRegionName);

// adjust your sprite position and dimensions here
final float xPos = 0;
final float yPos = 0;
final float w = asset.getWidth();
final float h = asset.getHeight();

// create sprite from given <atlasRegion>, with given dimensions <w> and <h>
// on the position of the given coordinates <xPos> and <yPos>
Sprite spr = new Sprite(atlasRegion, w, h, xPos, yPos);
```

Comment: Instead of creating a new `Sprite` out of a `AtlasRegion` you could directly creat it from the `TextureAtlas` with `atlas.createSprite(spritename)`. Also the `TextureFilter` can be set in the configuration of the `TexturePacker`, so it is set for the whole `TextureAtlas`.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. Textures in libgdx are automatically *managed* with or without an AssetManager, and therefore are automatically reloaded after a context loss.

Comment: In libgdx you can have managed and unmanaged textures. Hence you can indeed avoid using the AssetManager by ensuring your Textures are automatically managed. This is the case when Textures are loaded from a FileHandle, but you have to reload them manually in `resume()` and maybe in `resize()` method as well if they were loaded from Pixmap. To avoid this headache, I would recommend using an `AssetManager`.